SpeechSynthesisUtterance not cross browser?
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = "Hello World";
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

this make no sound whatsoever on brave and chrome browser, but it does in firefox

I can reproduce that failing - although that same code works after other working code, oddly.
This code works in both Chrome and Firefox (on Windows 11) for me:
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello World");
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

(I don't have Brave installed to test there.)
Passing the text into the constructor is inkeeping with the MDN sample code - but I still don't understand why the code you've shown only works sometimes. If my sample above works reliably for you, I'd use that...
